# Encoding difference UTF-8 Android 4.2.2 <=> Windows 7

Tags: java, android, windows, encoding, utf-8

I have a encoding problem. The same code produces different output on Android and Windows. I can't modify the Android application, therefore I need to find a solution on windows.
This is the code:

```
 public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    byte[] a = {-95, -10, -63, -74, 99, -10, 74, -56, -85, 105};
    String ab = new String(a,"UTF-8");
    System.out.println("out:"+Arrays.toString((new  StringBuilder(String.valueOf(ab))).toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
}
```

Output:

```
out:[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 118, 99, -17, -65, -67, 74, -56, -85, 105] (on Android)
out:[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 99, -17, -65, -67, 74, -56, -85, 105] (on Windows)
```

Android seems to use "java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]". Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works, using the code from String(byte[] data, int offset, int byteCount, Charset charset) in the java.lang.String class[1] from Android.

[1] http://android.yongbok.net/repository/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java

Answer (score 2):

This is because  {-95, -10, -63, -74, 99, -10, 74, -56, -85, 105} is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence. new String(bytes, "UTF-8") does not throw any exception in such situations but the result is difficult to predict. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 Invalid byte sequences section.

Try to use ISO-8859-1, it converts bytes to chars 1 : 1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. With ISO-8859-1 I get a 1:1 mapping, unfortunately I can't change the Android Code. I can only modify the windows code, is there a way to get the same output on windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `CharsetDecoder` then you can control the behaviour on malformed input. You can set [`CharsetDecoder.replaceWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#replaceWith%28java.lang.String%29) to a known string.

By default, [`Charset.decode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) will replace malformed input, but you can also specify [`CodingErrorAction.REPORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html#REPORT) instead to throw an exception and reject malformed input outright.

Otherwise, the name of the decoder implies that it is delegating to ICU. You may find [icu4j](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/)'s implementation of UTF-8 matches the Android behaviour.